# Closed formula involving $q$-binomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, finite-fields, closed-form, q-analogs

I was working on a combinatorial problem over finite fields, and the following quantity came up:

$$ \sum_{r=0}^k\, r\,\binom{n-k}{r}_q\,\binom{k}{k-r}_q\,q^{r^2},$$

where $k$ and $n$ are integers such that $0<k<\dfrac{n}{2}$,
and $\displaystyle\binom{a}{b}_q$ denotes the $q$-binomial. I am trying to understand if there is a closed formula for it.

In the case of the classical binomials I managed to prove that

$$ \sum_{r=0}^k \,r\,\binom{n-k}{r}\,\binom{k}{k-r}=(n-k)\,\binom{n-1}{k-1},$$
readapting the proof of the Vandermonde identity, but I don't know how to do it in the $q$-analog case. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Alessandro.

Comment: Are you sure you want to multiply each term in the sum by $r$? Would $\frac{(1 - q^r)}{(1 - q)}$ suffices too? (Which seems to be a more natural $q$-analogue of the classical formula)

Comment: @Noud Unfortunately yes. I'm not trying to find the $q$-analogue of the classical formula. I've just found this quantity doing some calculation in a problem involving rank metric codes and I was wondering if one could find a nicer formula for this sum.